# How to map over key-values in a map to produce another map with ImmutableJS?

Tags: immutable.js

How, using [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), do I produce a new map by mapping over the key/value pairs of an input map?

In Scala, I would do something like this:

```
scala> Map(1->2, 3->4).toSeq.map{case (k, v) => (k*k) -> (v*v*v)}.toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 8, 9 -> 64)
```

(This case trivially squares the key and cubes the value.)

In JavaScript, I'm hoping for something like:

```
Immutable.fromJS({1: 2, 3: 4}).map((v, k) => [k*k, v*v*v]).toJS()
// { 1: 8, 9: 64 }
```

(I'm using [ES6 via Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).)

I realize that this isn't guaranteed to produce a defined result, due to the potential key collision. In my application I am preventing this elsewhere.

I'm actually using an `OrderedMap`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: There is a `map()` function available https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/map

Comment: Hi Ben, the function passed to map is expected to return a new value. I'm looking for something that's expected to produce a new key/value pair, because I need to change both.

Comment: Good point, I clearly didn't the question properly

Answer (score 9):

The function I was looking for is [`mapEntries`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/mapEntries). Here's an example:

```
Immutable.fromJS({1: 2, 3: 4}).mapEntries(([k, v]) => [k*k, v*v*v]).toJS()
// { 1: 8, 9: 64 }
```

`mapEntries` takes a function that takes a key/value pair as an array, and should return the new key/value pair also as another array.